# tz_convert in pandas does not work for any city in India

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

the below command seems to work for a other locations in Asia except for any location in India. Is there a bug here or am I missing something?
this works:

```
pd.to_datetime(pd.datetime.now()).tz_localize('US/Pacific').tz_convert('Asia/Hong_Kong')
pd.to_datetime(pd.datetime.now()).tz_localize('US/Pacific').tz_convert('Asia/Karachi'
pd.to_datetime(pd.datetime.now()).tz_localize('US/Pacific').tz_convert('Asia/Dubai')
```

this does not work with exactly the same format (like any location in India):

```
pd.to_datetime(pd.datetime.now()).tz_localize('US/Pacific').tz_convert('Asia/New_Delhi')
```

throwing the below error

```
File "C:\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\pytz\__init__.py", line 180, in timezone
raise UnknownTimeZoneError(zone) UnknownTimeZoneError: 'Asia/New_Delhi'
```

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones for a list with time zones. You are probably looking for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asia/Kolkata

Comment: got it. Works with 'Kolkata'. I was not aware of the wikipedia list. Previously,  I did try Kolkatta with an extra 't' which seemed not to work! thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

pandas uses the the time zones in the tz database. You can find a list of all available time zone codes for example [in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

For India, you would use `Asia/Kolkata`

```
pd.to_datetime(pd.datetime.now()).tz_localize('US/Pacific').tz_convert('Asia/Kolkata')
```